# create-react-app with typescript not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I want to create a typescript react app by using this tool [Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter). I have followed the instructions from the github page:

```
1. npm install -g create-react-app

2. create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts

3. cd my-app

4. npm start
```

Then I get this error:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'process'
```

I have uninstalled create-react-app and reinstalled it. The error persists.
By the way yesterday I created a test program with the same tool and it worked.
When I run this test program, it works as expected.

But whatever application I create today with the tool throws the above exception. I think my installation is corrupted some how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This certainly has to do with the new 2.4 release of typescript which happened today. I upgraded typescript and see the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going back to typescript version 2.3.4 worked for me.

I used:

`npm install typescript@2.3.4`